# Will water run upwards if hose is placed up?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, fluid-statics, flow

At my house the hose bib is about 11FT below my deck, I want to run a hose straight up to the deck rail and then use that to connect a shorter watering hose so I have a water source on the deck.

I am thinking to use a stainless steel heavy duty gardening style hose OR a vinyl one.

Will the water go up?

Comment: Are there any 2-story houses in your neighborhood with bathrooms on the top floor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The pressure of your domestic water supply line is plenty enough to push water up 11 feet. I water the potted plants on my second-story deck in exactly this way and it works fine. I use ordinary 3/4" garden hose with a woven nylon braid inside.

The rule of thumb is this: 15 PSI will push water up about 33 feet, 30 PSI gives you 66 feet and 45 PSI will give you 99 feet. Most domestic water supply lines run between 45 PSI minimum and around 80 PSI maximum.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Great News!

Answer (score 1):

At 3 meters of depth  water pressure would be about 4.41 psi. If your water supply is greater than 4.41 psi then water will come out.